# How to translate the layout builder blocks of a node programmatically?

Tags: 9, layout-builder, i18n-l10n

I am translating the nodes programmatically. Everything works fine except the layout builder blocks.

When I try to translate it, it also changes on the source node.

I have created a node in language `en`. Now I am translating it to `nl`. Here is my code.

```
if ($node->hasTranslation($language)) {
  $translated_entity =  $node->getTranslation($language);
}
else {
  $translated_entity =  $entity->addTranslation($language);
}

$translated_layout = $node->get('layout_builder__layout')->getValue();

foreach ($translated_layout as $section) {
  /** @var \Drupal\layout_builder\Section $section */
  $section = reset($section);

  foreach ($section->getComponents() as $component) {
    $configuration = $component->get('configuration');

    $component->setConfiguration($translated_configurations);
  }
}

$translated_entity->set('layout_builder__layout', $translated_layout);
$translated_entity->save();
$node->save();
```

Is there any way to retain the original blocks as it is on the source node and the `save` function only added the changes to the translated node?

Comment: Is there a reason why you're doing this translation programmatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have done it myself. Here is the solution.

You first need to copy the layout from the source node to the translated node.

Then get the layout of the translated node and translate it.

```
if ($node->hasTranslation($language)) {
  $translated_entity =  $node->getTranslation($language);
}
else {
  $translated_entity =  $entity->addTranslation($language);
}

$translated_entity->set('layout_builder__layout', $node->get('layout_builder__layout')->getValue());
$translated_entity->save();

$translated_layout = $translated_entity->get('layout_builder__layout')->getValue();

foreach ($translated_layout as $section) {
  /** @var \Drupal\layout_builder\Section $section */
  $section = reset($section);

  foreach ($section->getComponents() as $component) {
    $configuration = $component->get('configuration');

    $component->setConfiguration($translated_configurations);
  }
}

$translated_entity->set('layout_builder__layout', $translated_layout);     
$node->save();
```

Comment: What are you doing in the foreach loops? The `$configuration` variable is not used?